# Take href value, store in variable and remove the http://

Tags: jquery, string, variables, href

I've been trying on and off all afternoon with no luck. What I need to be able to do is take the `href=""` value of a link and store it in a new variable or new attribute (inside the `a`), but having had the `http://` removed beforehand. This would keep the `href` value the same so that it still points to the link but I have a version without the http:// as well.

So far, this is the code i've tried:

```
$("a[href]").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).replace('http://', '');
});
```

I think this is correct but I'm not very good at jQuery or JS so I'd really appreciate if someone could finish it off/start from scratch :)

Eventually, I want to be able to put the link without the http:// into a pseudo-element of the  `a`, using `a:before`.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dSHH4/) as well.

Thank you very much to anyone who helps me out.

Comment: Use `this.href` instead of `$(this)`.

Comment: Can't target psuedo-selectors with javascript/jQuery. Won't be able to do a:before and add content.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy can we not just set a new attribute on the link and use that in the a:before, using content: attr(new); in the CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `this.href` instead of `$(this)`.

If you want to handle `https` as well as `http`, you can use a regex:

```
var link = this.href.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '');
```

Also, since you want to display this value in a `:after` pseudo-element, store `link` in a data attribute. That way, you can grab the value directly from CSS:

```
$("a[href]").each(function() {
    var link = this.href.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '');

    $(this).attr('data-href', link);
});
```

And then change your CSS to:

```
a:before {
    content: 'This link goes to ' attr(data-href);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dSHH4/1/**

Answer (score 3):

a[href] doesn't select href attribute it selects elements with this attribute so you have to call attribute manual:

```
$("a[href]").each(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('href').replace('http://', '');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple I would do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var withhref = $("a").attr("href"); alert(withhref);
        var withouthref = $("a").attr("href").replace("http://","");  alert(withouthref);

    })
    </script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4bbdj/)